# Вывод чисел внутри прямоугольника сверху вниз

Tags: c

Я пытаюсь написать код который принимает 3 переменные obrazec = то что программа мне отрисует, a = ширина фигуры т.е. количество символов по горизонтали и b = высота фигуры и который при получении obrazec = 9, a = num, b = num2 выводил бы прямоугольник обрамленный "x" а в центре которого были бы цифры от 0 до 9 размером a на б по типу:

```
xxxxxxxx
x036925x
x147036x
x258147x
xxxxxxxx
```

На данный момент я написал такой код

```
if (obrazec == 2)
{
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < a; ii++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == b - 1 || ii == 0 || ii == a - 1) 
            {
                printf("x");
            } else {
                printf("%d", num % 10);
                num++;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Который выводит числа, но по горизонтали, как я могу сделать чтоб они шли по вертикали как в примере?

Comment: Выводить по горизонтали *нужные* числа...

Comment: А если obrazec > 9, что в этом случае должна отрисовать программа?

Comment: @LShadow77, в случае если Obrazec != 9 то программа отрисовывает другие фигуры в зависимости от того чему равна данная переменная

Comment: Ну тут, как говорится, какое тз, такое и хз. Значит мой ответ не нужен)